# Удалить "грязь" из элементов append select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, у меня небольшой кусок кода куда добавляется вся информация из списка

```
$("#UserActive").append("<option value='" + item.FullName +"'>"+ item.FullName + '' + "</option>");
```

но лезут все данные, т.е. "грязь" типа null и undefined, как ее удалить сразу в цикле? Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: ну так перед вставкой проверить и не вставлять

Comment: этот не ответ..

Comment: правильно, это комментарий. Так в чем проблема проверить, что текущие данные _"грязь"_ и не вставлять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался:

```
$('#UserActive').find('option:contains('+ 'null' +')').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item && item.FullName && $("#UserActive").append("<option value='" + item.FullName +"'>"+ item.FullName + '' + "</option>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#UserActive").append(function(){
if(item.FullName){
return "<option value='" + item.FullName +"'>"+ item.FullName + '' + "   </option>";
}});
```